# problem forecasting in R using a VAR model : interpretation of characteristic polynomial roots

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, rms, bivariate

I have the following R code, I am fitting a VAR(10) models to a bivariate time series, comprising two variables, gaz and nuc. Yet, when trying to forecast, I had negative values, whereas my series is the nuclear electricity production and the total imports of gaz by France, from november 2003 to november 2022. So negative values are impossible.
I wonder the cause of this, as my model passed the ARCH test, the serial tests too, but not the Jarque-Bera test.
Maybe it is not stationary, but I do not know how to interpret the value of the roots of the characteristic polynomial in R, which you can see here, performed on 4 different models [image].

I tried to perform an RMSE test, but it didn't work, because R doesn't recognise that start_date is before end_date :

```
  library(lubridate)  
  start_date <- ymd("2003-11-01")  
  end_date <- ymd("2021-12-01")  
  subset_data <- window(energy.bv, start = start_date, end = end_date)

  Modelenergy2_test <- VAR(subset_data, p = 10, season = 12, type = "both")
  forecast_2022 <- predict(Modelenergy2_test, n.ahead = 11, ci = 0)
  actual_2022 <- window(energy.bv, start = ymd("2022-01-01"), end = ymd("2022-11-01"))
  library(Metrics)
  rmse <- RMSE(forecast_2022$Nucléaire, actual_2022$Nucléaire)
```

I get the following error after subset data :
Error in window.default(x, ...) : 'start' ne peut pas être après 'end'
In addition: Warning message:
In window.default(x, ...) : valeur de 'end' inchangée

Here is my code :

```
  lagSelect<-VARselect(energy.bv,lag.max = 10,type="both")
  lagSelect<-VARselect(energy.bv,lag.max = 10,type="both")$selection
  lagSelect
  Modelenergy2 <- VAR(energy.bv, p = 10, type = "both", season = 12)
  summary(Modelenergy2)
```

Here is the summary of the model :[image] [image] [image] [image]

Any help would be welcome, thanks in advance !